# unable to import python file into another file

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am basically working with python(beginner) on visual studio and stuck on importing a python file into another python file.I am working on an assignment it has 3 files a , b and test_a while making a function in file 'a' and importing that file into test_a to test a function but didn't get answer
I tried this line for importing  file 'a' in 'test_a' like this but unable to import

```
from a import *
```

any idea how to import a whole file into another ?

Comment: Are both `a` and `test_a` in the same folder? And did you get any error while trying the above line?

Comment: yes i made a project and add .py files into that project and No i am not getting any error  :/

Comment: If you are not getting any error, then what is your issue?

Comment: i failed to  access functions of a in test_a file

Comment: I had similar problem in Jupyter notebook, the import filename was successful but unable to get the class. Restarting the Jupyter kernal helped me fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both files `a` and `a_test` are in the same folder, you should be able to call methods from `a` (even when they're not in sys.path):

a.py

```
def hello():
    print 'Hello'
```

a_test.py

```
from a import *
hello()
```

Returns `'Hello'` if I run `a_test.py`. Does this minimal example work for you?

Remember certain imports (with names like `file`) can cause problems if they're already python core modules.

Comment: I did a silly mistake , I didnt run my file i ran my whole project that causes nothing .. now all are up to the mark

Comment: Ah, that must've been it. Glad to hear it worked. Please consider voting up my answer if it was any helpful discovering the actual error.

Comment: Sure it helped me to run a single file instead whole project

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to ensure that the module you'd like to import exists along `sys.path`. This is a list of directories python uses when searching on disk for modules and packages.

To add a location to `sys.path`, you can set `PYTHONPATH` in your environment to include the directory where your module lives.

Check out:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path

Answer (score 0):

You must check if file 'a' is in same folder or its in sys.path folder where all the libraries of python are. By seeing your situation, you should have the other file in same folder.

You can also check: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Importing_Modules

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to import the file "a", then just `import a` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set lib path on your project

1. right click your project
2. open properties
3. open debug
4. write folder path that contain file that you want to import into Search Paths of "Run" group box
5. now you can import python file of other folder

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio thus provides a means to specify search paths directly in both environments and projects. Code that you run or debug in Visual Studio receives search paths in the value of PYTHONPATH (and other equivalent variables). By adding search paths, Visual Studio inspects the libraries in those locations and builds IntelliSense databases for them when needed (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 and earlier; constructing the database may take some time depending on the number of libraries).
>
> To add a search path, go to Solution Explorer, expand your project node, right-click on Search Paths, select Add Folder to Search Path:

This link from the official documentation worked for [me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/search-paths?view=vs-2019).